# SQL_Data_Manipulation

Tags: sql

```
     Indicator   Letter   Number  Value
1    Control       A       119    1494
2    Test          A       119    1083
3    Control       A       121    834
4    Test          A       121    638
5    Control       B       121    319
6    Test          B       121    378
```

I want to create a new column that runs a calculation between test and control where letter and number equal the same thing between test and control. So for example the top two rows would be (1083-1494)/1083

Comment: Don't sabotage edits, please

Answer (score 1):

Should work like that:

```
SELECT letter, number, (test.value - control.value) / test.value as result
FROM t as control
JOIN t as test 
ON
  control.letter = test.letter AND
  control.number = test.number AND 
  control.indicator = 'Control' AND 
  test.indicator = 'Test'
```

EDIT (for division by zero): Depending on how you want to handle the 0 value, the most general solution is `CASE` expression

```
SELECT 
  letter, 
  number, 
  CASE WHEN test.value IS NULL OR test.value = 0 
    THEN 'Undefined'
    ELSE (test.value - control.value) / test.value 
  END AS result
FROM t AS control
JOIN t AS test 
ON
  control.letter = test.letter AND
  control.number = test.number AND 
  control.indicator = 'Control' AND 
  test.indicator = 'Test'
```